# SQLDeveloper UI crashes when opened

Tags: linux, oracle, ubuntu, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm facing problems with Oracle SQLDeveloper and I don't know how to solve this.

I installed JDK 18 in my Ubuntu 22.04 and each time I try to open SQLDeveloper I got this error.

```
java.lang.Error: no ComponentUI class for: oracle.ide.controls.StatusBarControl$JDevStatusBar[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=0,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.UIDefaults.getUIError(UIDefaults.java:763)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.MultiUIDefaults.getUIError(MultiUIDefaults.java:144)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.UIDefaults.getUI(UIDefaults.java:793)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.UIManager.getUI(UIManager.java:1073)
    at oracle.bali.ewt.statusBar.StatusBar.updateUI(StatusBar.java:480)
    at oracle.bali.ewt.statusBar.StatusBar.<init>(StatusBar.java:104)
    at oracle.ide.controls.StatusBarControl$JDevStatusBar.<init>(StatusBarControl.java:264)
    at oracle.ide.controls.StatusBarControl.<init>(StatusBarControl.java:48)
    at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbMainWindow$13.<init>(NbMainWindow.java:1098)
    at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbMainWindow.createStatusBar(NbMainWindow.java:1098)
    at oracle.ide.IdeMainWindow.getStatusBar(IdeMainWindow.java:622)
    at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbMainWindow.getStatusBarStatic(NbMainWindow.java:228)
    at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbStatusBar.getStatusLineElement(NbStatusBar.java:23)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.MainWindow$7.run(MainWindow.java:426)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.MainWindow.getStatusLineElements(MainWindow.java:438)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.MainWindow.decoratePanel(MainWindow.java:392)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.MainWindow.access$100(MainWindow.java:81)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.MainWindow$2.run(MainWindow.java:269)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.WindowManagerImpl$Exclusive$1.run(WindowManagerImpl.java:1563)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

I already tried to reinstall SQLDeveloper and JDK 18 too. Nothing changed!

Comment: I installed JDK 18 -- no. We only support JDK 8 and 11. Although 17 should also still work. I have NO IDEA what will happen with 18.

Comment: Yes, I changed my JDK version to 11. It worked here. Thanks!